# Определить количество способов добраться до последней клетки

Tags: типы-данных, c++

Привет. Задача такая: дана клетчатая доска NxM (-1000 <= N,M <= 1000), мы находимся в самой первой клетке 1-1. Нужно определить количество способов добраться до последней клетки N-M. Можно двигаться только вправо и вниз, также на доске существуют препятствия с известными координатами, через них пройти нельзя.
Входные данные (Пример):
3 3 - размеры доски
1 - кол-во преград
2 2 - координаты преграды

Так как в конце может получиться большое число, требуют в ответе написать остаток от деления на 1000000007.

В общем-то я сделал: http://ideone.com/3N8Nsk Для простых тестовых примеров работает, а вот для БОЛЬШИХ тестовых примеров 1000х1000 например, думаю, работает неправильно. Потому что в компиляторе на компьютере ответ один, на онлайн компиляторе ответ другой. Думаю, что неправильные типы у меня. Помогите.

Comment: Попробуйте все считать в `long long`. 

Это независимые от архитектуры компьютера 64-разрядные целые числа.

Comment: может N, M > 0? а то как это, размер доски отрицателен?
avp, по условию, количество способов не превышает 1000000007. предел - 4294967295 (обычный 4-х байтный unsigned long)? или нет?

Comment: Верно, от 1 до 1000

Comment: ниже ответ, пробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделал немного другой алгоритм, действительно, если 1000х1000 и нет преград, получается катастрофически большое число вариантов - 2874513998398909184
На наборе

```
1000 1000
1
2 2
```

ответ вышел (с учетом %1000000007)

```
404725643
```

Вывод: используйте unsigned long long

p.s. в качестве бонуса/интереса - попробуйте мой алгоритм прогнать в системе + посмотрите как можно чуть упростить алгоритм. Тестировал в VC++, в GCC не знаю почему, на любых данных - выводит ноль, однако, если использовать дебаггер и пошаговую отладку - выводит правильные значения
http://pastebin.com/Bry1smqV#